# What are the p2 repository URLs for Eclipse 4.x releases?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2, tycho, target-platform

For an Eclipse plugin project I use Maven and Tycho to build it. The Tycho configuration for target platform is

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <resolver>p2</resolver>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The repository is declared as

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>${platform-version-name}</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>${eclipse-site}</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and the values are declared as

```
<properties>
    <platform-version-name>galileo</platform-version-name>
    <eclipse-site>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/${platform-version-name}</eclipse-site>
</properties>
```

This is the approach shown in all tutorials. Using this approach I can test my plugin for every version it should support (3.5 and up). Success.

BUT I wasn't able to figure out the proper URLs for the 4.x releases, so I could also test against 4.0 and 4.1 and possibly 4.2 Nightly.

**Can I use the same approach to use Eclipse 4.x as a target platform and what would be the p2 repository URLs?**

Comment: Why this lengthy question if all you wanted to know is a URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites

Comment: I see. I was using the whole release train update sites instead of the plain Eclipse update sites and there is no release train release of 4.x Eclipse versions. Thanks.